# TableView indexPath Error

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a problem . The index of the first element of the array is 1 and not 0.Why? If I click button that print the index. The first element of the tableview that it is 0 , in reality is 1

```
var posts = [Post]()
var index = 0

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let currentPost = self.posts[indexPath.row]
    index = indexPath.row
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell

    cell.config(currentPost, updateManager: self)
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell

}


@IBAction func displayAction(_ sender: Any) {
    print(index)
    if(posts[index].userID == uid) {

    let alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alertcontroller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "test", style: .default, handler: self.deletepost))
    alertcontroller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "report", style: .default, handler: nil))
    alertcontroller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(alertcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alertcontroller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "report", style: .default, handler: nil))
        alertcontroller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alertcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? And never rely on the order that `cellForRowAt` is called, it's irrelevant.

Comment: the index of the first element of table view is 0 but the index is 1 .Why=

Comment: where you print it ?

Comment: I just told you why. Don't rely on the order that `cellForRowAt` is called. Why do you set some `index` property based on the index path used in each `cellForRowAt`? It will change in unpredictable ways as the table is displayed and scrolled. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: in the console with a function of button

Comment: based on the cell, I need the array's index

Comment: Where is the `index` variable used?  If you're trying to use one variable for the index of every cell, that's probably the problem.

Comment: how resolve it?

Comment: I don't know, because you haven't shown the code where you're using it.

Comment: I use the index in a function of button

Comment: Consider adding more details or at least explain what are you trying to achieve. Respect the others' time, currently your question is a riddle, so they'll have to spend a lot of time trying to decode it.

Comment: Where is this button? Is there a button in each cell? Is there just one button in the view controller show near the table view? You need to [edit] your question with useful details. It's difficult to help when your question lacks sufficient details.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try this to register every cell with post index inside `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row
```

//

```
@IBAction func displayAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(index)
    if(posts[sender.tag].userID == uid) {

}
```

Comment: Did you tried it ? , if so post that code and clarify the exact process

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: how do you tried accessing that tag after you assigned it , when do you want the index of the post , what the action ??

Comment: cell.tag = indexPath.row. and index = cell.tag

Comment: where you try **index = cell.tag**

Comment: Nope Nope Nope , don't do this , When do you want that index ? is it a button action inside the cell , or action in the VC containing the table ??

Comment: it is a button inside the cell but the action is in the viewcontroller because I want to insert an alert

Comment: can you show me that code snippet ??? , Also use cell.tag to index the array the var index you declare inside the VC is a misleading var

Comment: I add the function in VC of the button inside the cell of the table view

Comment: hook the btn as IBOutlet inside the cell custom class and do what in answer

Comment: if I have this function: func delete (alert : UIAlertAction) {
      
    }